# Proof that $AI_n = A$ using $Ab_i$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this problem which I understand, but can't put into mathematical words.

Let $A$ denote a nxn matrix and let $b_i$ denote the nx1 column vector whose i-th entry is equal to 1 and whose other entries are equal to 0.

Prove that $Ab_i$ is equal to the i-th column of A.

**Answer**

The matrix A can be presented in the following form:

$A = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11}&a_{12}&\dots&a_{1i}&\dots&a_{1n}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&\dots&a_{2i}&\dots&a_{2n} \\ \dots \end{pmatrix}$

Then, $Ab_i$ will yield the ith-column of A.

---

Now, let $I_n$ denote the nun matrix. Using the fact that $Ab_i$ is equal to the i-th column of A, prove that $AI_n = A$.

I want to say that $I_n = (b_1 + b_2 + \dots + b_n)$ but that is not true as far as matrix addition is concerned. I would need to replace $+$ by some "append" operator...

After, I would say

$$AI_n = A(b_1 + b_2 + \dots + b_n) = Ab_1 + Ab_2 + \dots + Ab_n = A$$ because each $Ab_i$ yields a unique column of A, thus "recreating $A$".

Comment: I think you want to use the fact that the ith column of $AI_{n}$ is equal to $Ab_i$, since $b_i$ is the ith column of $I_n$, along with the fact that multiplying A by a column vector gives the corresponding linear combination of the columns of A.

Comment: Let $I_n$ be the row vector that consists of the column vectors $b_i's$ and define $A_i=Ab_i$. Then $AI_n=A(b_1 ... b_n)=(Ab_1 ... Ab_n)=(A_1 ... A_n)=A$

Comment: @ChristopherErnst, how is $I_n = (b_1\dots b_n)$? Is the definition using matrix multiplication?

Comment: Defining $I_n$ this way absolutely allows matrix multiplication.  What is matrix multiplication?  It is a sequence of dot products, or you could say multiple row vectors by multiple column vectors...

Comment: OK so if I understand well, $I_n = [b_1 b_2 b_3 \dots b_n]$ where each $b_i$ is a column vector. When you say $A(b_1\dots b_n)$, is $(b_1\dots b_n)$ a matrix or $b_1 \cdot b_2 \cdot \dots \cdot b_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are defining the matrix as a row vector whose elements are column vectors.  So you define a couple of items;

Let $\mathbf{b}_i$ be the column vector $ \begin{bmatrix}
        b_1 \\
        \vdots \\
        b_i \\
        \vdots \\
        b_n \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$ whose $i$'th entry is $1$ and $0$ otherwise.  Thus, $\mathbf{b}_2=\begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \vdots \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

Also, for our matrix $A$, we define $A_i=A\mathbf{b}_i$, which we know is the $i$'th row of our matrix $A$.

Finally, define $I_n=(\mathbf{b}_1 ... \mathbf{b}_i ... \mathbf{b}_n)$.  This is a row vector whose elements are the column vectors.  There are no operations between these vectors like $+$ or $\cdot$.  Thus, you can see that our $I_n$ is just the identity matrix written a little differently.  Now using only properties of matrix multiplication,
$$AI_n=A(\mathbf{b}_1 ... \mathbf{b}_i ... \mathbf{b}_n)=(A\mathbf{b}_1...A\mathbf{b}_i...A\mathbf{b}_n)=(A_1...A_i...A_n)=A$$

Now, this entire argument is based on the fact that matrix multiplication on a vector is in fact a linear transformation.  I have not gone through the whole argument here for simplicity sake (the argument involves properties of Linear Tranformations, coordinate vectors, etc), but in reality think of what is happening here... Each row of $A$ is being multiplied by each individual column vector and producing the column of A, because of the make up of our defined $I_n$.

If we define the rows of $A$ as $\mathbf{a}_i$, then matrix multiplication is just the dot product of rows of $A$ with columns of $I_n$, so the first element, $\mathbf{a}_1 \cdot \mathbf{b}_1=\sum_{k=1}^n{a_{1,k}b_k}=a_{1,1}b_1...+a_{1,n}b_n=a_{1,1}$, since $b_1=1$ and $b_j=0, j\neq{1}$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I had a hard time visualizing the matrices but you made it very clear. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is what your professor is looking for, but this is how I learned to employ matrix multiplication; column by column.  Eventually, (unless you have already) you learn that a linear transformation on a vector, $T(v)$ can be written as matrix multiplication where the matrix is $m\times n$ and the vector is $n \times 1$, so that $T(v)=Av$